# Flex-wrap:wrap-reverse in Edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

In the following sample, the flex items start flowing from the top-right corner of the wrapper:

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid teal;
}

#wrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

#wrap div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

But this is how I see them in Edge:

[image]

And with `flex-direction: row;` they look like this:

[image]

But this is how they look in Edge:

[image]

Is Edge behaving correctly?

Comment: For me it wraps the same in Edge and Chrome ... which Edge version do you use?

Comment: What if you add `justify-content: flex-end` or `align-items: flex-end` to the flex container?

Comment: Edge appeared to have this bug in a version dated April, 2016: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7311857/

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Edge 15063, [See here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7311857/)

Comment: @LGSon: Mine is version 13.10586.

Comment: So that is the older one, which has the issue ... the fixed one has only been released as an Insider Preview, but with the Creators Update that comes this month (April), all will get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge appeared to have [this bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7311857/) in a version dated April, 2016.

In the report it's stated (on March 29, 2017), that from version 15063 this bug have been fixed.

---

*Side note: It also appears that the fixed one has only been released as an Insider Preview, but with the Creators Update that comes this month (April, 2017), all should get it*